# Sony Vaio E Series SVE15113EN brightness issue

Tags: brightness

I have a ony Vaio E Series SVE15113EN laptop. I am using a dual boot system with Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. In Ubuntu I am unable to adjust the brightness either by using Fn keys or by the default brightness adjust settings from system settings. The hot keys slide but no changes and the same is with the option from system settings menu in Ubuntu.

There are many threads here regarding this issue in this forum, but none has given a precise answer. That is the reason why I am opened a new thread. If this thread is duplicate kindly merge it with the relevant one. My eyes hurt from the extreme brightness from the screen forcing me to resort to windows. I think this laptop has a built in Intel HD graphics.

Hope to receive an answer from the experts here.

Thanking you all in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal ctrl+alt+t
and enter this command

```
sudo gedit /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

then put your password.

A file would open up.

Set the number in it to 0 (minimuim) if it isn't and save (ctrl+s) then reboot your PC.

If you are getting error related to back up then close above file as it has to be deleted and do

```
sudo rm /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

then try again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But when I type in 0 and then try to save it is showing that it is unable to make a backup copy of the file so save anyway. I clicked "save anyway", but it does not save. Is there anything that I am missing?. Awaiting for your reply.

Comment: Did it show any error or something? please tell.

Comment: Yes Pulkit, this is the error "Could not create a backup file while saving /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness", gedit could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new one. You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, but if an error occurs while saving, you could lose the old copy of the file. Save anyway?. But when I give save anyway, it doesn't get saved. Please help me.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Pulkit, this is the error I am getting <- "rm: cannot remove `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness': Operation not permitted".

Comment: Try sudo su first .